# Warning for clang's shifting bare integer values default to 32 bit

Tags: c, clang

So, in the upstream sources, we have this line

```
rc_c_max = allmem - (3 << 30);
```

Upstream which typically uses gcc, does things "as expected". `allmem` is uint64_t. 
But with clang, it appears to assume "3" is 32 bit (or maybe signed) and the results are not "as expected". An easy fix for it is to change it to

```
rc_c_max = allmem - (3ULL << 30);
```

and everything works. Changing all the bare-interger shifts, by working out/guessing which needs to be corrected is tedious, **is there a warning I can enable for clang to point this out?** `-Wall -Wextra` does not complain about this line.

Output:

```
1/19/16 9:25:30.000 AM kernel[0]: allmem - (3 << 30) : 0x373333000 : 14817636352
1/19/16 9:25:30.000 AM kernel[0]: allmem - (3ULL << 30) : 0x273333000 : 10522669056
```

Comment: `3` has type `signed int`. You should always be thinking about types when writing code containing shifts .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag you are looking for is:

```
-Wshift-sign-overflow
```

Although, unlike gcc, I recommend using clang's compiler flag:

```
-Weverything
```

That would enable `-Wshift-sign-overflow` as well.

Comment: Perfect, showed one more in my code, and one in XNU sources which would be harder to fix :)